# Ionic liquids and deep eutectic solvent cation vs anion shape

Tags: ionic-compounds

If we consider an ionic liquid of a deep eutectic such as the choline chloride type DESs, why are ionic liquids (and deep eutectics) with not very symmetric cations and very symmetric anions more common than ionic liquids which are the other way around.

Consider for example Choline chloride (plus ethylene glycol) and butyl-methylimidazonium hexafluorophosphate

Comment: Complex anions are labile - exchange ligands till equilibrium. You just can't get most of mixed ligand inorganic anions.